# Save column names when extracting columns by variable name

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data.table.

```
dt = data.table(one=rep(2,4), two=rnorm(4))
dt
```

Now I have created a variable with a name of one column.

```
col_name = "one"
```

If I want to return that column as a data.table, I can do one of the following. The first option will return the column name as V1 and the second will actually set the column name to "one".

```
dt[,.(get(col_name))]
dt[,col_name, with=FALSE]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the column name which using the get command. Something like the following, which doesn't work.

```
dt[,as.symbol(col_name) = .(get(col_name))]
```

The reason that I need the column names with get is that I have pretty extensive loop whereby I'm filling in empty columns. So it could end up looking like this, whereby I loop through and replace imp_val with the median by the columns in cols.

```
  dat2[is.na(get(imp_val)),  
              as.symbol(imp_val) := dat2[.BY, median(get(imp_val), na.rm=TRUE), on=get(cols)], by=c(get(cols))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can specify it in the `.SDcols`

```
dt[, .SD,.SDcols = col_name]
```

Or with `..`

```
dt[, ..col_name]
```

---

if the intention is to rename the column as 'col_name'

```
setnames(dt[, ..col_name], deparse(substitute(col_name)))[]
#   col_name
#1:        2
#2:        2
#3:        2
#4:        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the tidyverse approach for this. Setup:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
dt = data.table(one=rep(2,4), two=rnorm(4))
col_name = "one"
```

Then use `select` with the non-standard evaluation operator `!!` (pronounced bang-bang):

```
> dt %>% dplyr::select(!!col_name)
one
1:   2
2:   2
3:   2
4:   2
```

The returned object is still a `data.table`:

```
> dt %>% 
    dplyr::select(!!col_name) %>% 
    class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I'm not sure what you mean with the second part of your question on replacing NAs with the median. Maybe you could update your answer with a small example?